# Making BJAM 1.33.1 in boost compile with Microsoft Visual Studio 8

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, bjam

When trying to build a boost 1.33.1 library with bjam, I keep getting thousands of errors with command similar to this:

```
 CALL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\bin\VCVARS32.BAT" >nul
```

Is there any way to change where bjam searchs for Microsoft Visual Studio for boost 1.33.1?  My Visual Studio installation is located in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8"

Comment: The first question is, why do you want to use a nearly-6-year-old version of Boost? That's downright ancient in C++ terms...

Comment: I agree that it is very ancient, but my hands are tied on the version I am able to use.

Comment: Fair enough. Are you running from inside a 'Visual Studio Command Prompt' (installing VC++ 2005 should add a start-menu shortcut named similarly)? If not, you should be -- bjam relies on existing environment variables to figure out what version of VC++ to build with, and only calls VCVARS32.BAT if it can't find them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried this in the VS 2005 Command Prompt but it still does the same call to the VC98 directory.  I have no idea where it's getting this path from.

Comment: You _might_ be able to use the bjam from a later version of Boost to compile an earlier version. Or perhaps you could adapt the Boost build system from later versions, essentially back-porting it into earlier ones.

Comment: @Nicol : Nope, Boost.Build went from v1 to v2 between 1.33.1 and 1.34.0. Consequently, all versions of bjam from any later version of Boost are utterly incompatible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nicol,  I actually tried using a bjam executable I compiled for boost 1.46.0.  It produced the same issue.

Comment: @Christopher : Did you build bjam yourself, from the source in `tools/build/jam_src`? If not, you probably have the wrong version of bjam, and that's causing your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the suggestions ildjarn and Nicol Bolas.

I did a manual text search for VC98 and found an HTML help file, msvc-tools.html, which states that if the MSVC_ROOT variable defaults to "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98" if not specified.  I simply set the MSVC_ROOT variable to my Visual Studio 8 directory and things compiled.